# inexplicable mod_rewrite behavior

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, typo3

I have her a typo3 installation with following mod_rewrite rule:

Just for understand mod_rewrite I wan't to create the following rule.

If someone request with no uri like "http://domain.com" and accept-language en I want to route to /index.php?id=1&L=1

This is my .htaccess

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
   RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?id=1&L=1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

I get a 500 error. In apache logfile:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 188.24.87] r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Fri Jul 25 14:14:59 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 188.24.87] redirected from r->uri = /
```

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, but your last rule gets executed multiple times, because the `.*` matches `index.php` after the initial rewrite. Change it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php) /index.php [L]
```